# Using Codeigniter 4 Email Credentials

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

When i send the mail it will go but, will have this error:

> ErrorException MessageFormatter::formatMessage(): Creating message
> formatter failed

Here is the email credentials

```
$config['SMTPHost'] = 'smtp.mailtrap.io';
$config['SMTPUser'] = '71xxxxxxxxx';
$config['SMTPPass'] = '3dxxxxxxxxx';
$config['SMTPPort'] = 2525;
$config['SMTPCrypto'] = 'tls';
$config['mailType'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this with your entire email configuration code

```
//* Initialize email class
$config['SMTPHost'] = 'smtp.mailtrap.io';
$config['SMTPUser'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
$config['SMTPPass'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
$config['SMTPPort'] = 2525;
$config['SMTPCrypto'] = 'tls';

//* Prepare the emai destination
$email = \Config\Services::email();
$email->initialize($config);
$email->setFrom(user@domain.com, sender name);
$email->setTo(you@mail.com);
$email->setSubject('Test email');
$email->setMessage('Testing');
if($email->send())
{
    return TRUE;
}
else
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: That means i dont need the parameters below?
$config['mailType'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";